# How to use getSystemService for Android notification channel

Tags: java, android

So in the Android developer Docs (https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification) it gives this line to create a notification channel:

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
```

But with the exact code block copied I get the error:

```
cannot find symbol method getSystemService(Class<NotificationManager>)
```

I think that's a method but wasn't called from it's class (Context)? But then why is in the docs? What should I put instead?

Answer (score 1):

> But then why is in the docs?

The docs assume that this line of code is in a method of some implementation of `Context`, such as an `Activity` or `Service`.

> What should I put instead?

Either:

- Move this code into a method of some implementation of `Context`, such as an `Activity` or `Service`, or
- Call `getSystemService()` on some instance of `Context`

We cannot give you more specific advice without knowing more about where you are attempting to use that line of code.

Comment: ah I see my mistake in interpreting the docs, thank you!